# Scroll linear layout beyond the content

Tags: android, scroll

I think that this is a simple question but I can't figure it out, I have a Scroll View with some text inside and it works perfectly, it only enables scrolling when the content doesn't fit into the screen. The thing is that I want to scroll the content no matter if it fits or not until the last line of the text reach the top of the view leaving blank space below and obviously "hiding" the content above it. I don't know if I'm explaining myself very well, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dummy view with height equal to the height of device's screen beneath your textview in scrollView.

Comment: Thanks, this partially solved my problem, but with this method the content will scroll way beyond the last line of text, what I really need is to stop scrolling when the last line of text is in at the top of the scroll view but it needs to be still visible. I think it would be easily fixed with a maxHeight for the scroll view but I can't find that either

Comment: You can get the height of textview and adjust the height of dummy view accordingly